# Joomla site security

Tags: php, security, joomla

How we can secure our Joomla site from outsider user.

Is there is any security feature is available in Joomla to prevent it hacking from outsider user.

Comment: Do not upload it if you want to  prevent it from hacking.

Comment: @swapnesh Prevention is better than cure....!!!

Comment: If you still use joomla 1.x upgrade to v2.

Comment: honestly, who still uses Joomla 1.x ?

Comment: sadly lots of people still on 1.0 - usually with heavily customised code...

Answer (score 2):

Use this following steps :

Change the default database prefix (jos_)

Use a SEF component

Use the correct CHMOD for each folder and file.

Password protect your administrative area.

Keep your website up-to-date.

Use a .htaccess file to secure your Joomla.

Passwords - Use a unique and strong password.

Install the jSecure Authentication plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [phpids.org](http://phpids.org/)
As an intrusion detection system, It mitigates web bases attacks.

Answer (score 1):

1. All sites can be hacked, the best you can do is be pro-active against that day.
2. Read the [Joomla! doc's on Security](http://docs.joomla.org/Security)
3. The most effective exploits have been through `/administrator` so, put `/administrator` under it's own authrealm and only provide that password to trusted users. (Then change it every time a `/administrator` users leaves.)
4. Use [JSecure](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/12254) with a changing token.
5. Run a content monitoring system in conjunction with a continuous back system so you can minimise downtime if/when you do get hacked (that way you're notified of the problem quick and can restore quickly to a working state). (You may want to investigate [Akeeba](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606) for automated backups)
6. Don't use obvious names for Administrator or Super Admin accounts (e.g. admin/superadmin/root etc) and disable the original admin account from when the site was setup.
7. As mentioned in Joomla's doc's keep your site up-to-date with both the installed Joomla! version and any third-party extensions (especially keep an eye on the [Vulnerable Extensions list](http://docs.joomla.org/Vulnerable_Extensions_List))

Answer (score 1):

I believe I answered this question here. Might come in handy for you too

[Joomla! 2.5.4 Hacked: Having trouble with diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036763/joomla-2-54-hacked-having-trouble-with-diagnosis/11037642#11037642)