# How to migrate joomla 1.5.18 to 1.5.20 - hacked

Tags: joomla, backup, joomla1.5

Hi some one hacked my joomla site,

I am not able to access to "administrator/index.php?option=com_config", it is giving 404 error. 
The hacker is "hacked by s13doeL", he added "joomla.class.php and index.old.php" in all over the web files.

I think there is only one solution, reistall everything. 
Could someone help to migrate from 1.5.18 to 1.5.20. I do not want to change to 2.5 because that template is not supported to 2.5.

Is it just enough copy all database and then link to it? Does it copy all old articles? or do I have to copy ann manualy?

Comment: While it is unfortunate that this has happened, this is not the site to get that information.  I hope you have learned a valuable lesson about keeping things patched and configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say this but it's really your own fault. Not only are you using an unsupported version of Joomla, but an old version in that series as well. The latest version of the Joomla 1.5 series is 1.5.26 so there should be no reason why you weren't using that.

I answered a question regarding being hacked and gave some advice along with recommended extensions to use. The guy was using Joomla 2.5 but it can still apply to Joomla 1.5.

[Joomla! 2.5.4 Hacked: Having trouble with diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036763/joomla-2-5-4-hacked-having-trouble-with-diagnosis/11037642#11037642)

So remember, in future, keep up to date else it's to your detriment.

**Update:**

To upgrade from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5, install this extension. This will update the core Joomla stuff and database tables. Do bare in mind that it will not upgrade 3rd party extensions, therefore you will need to upload the 2.5 compatible versions yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am thinking to install the latest version of joomla 2.5.x, are there any way to copy all my articles, categories, section to the new version? Is it just enough to integrate data base?