# No Able to show content of website on joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5

I have pushed my `joomla` website content to `bigrock server`to host the website. But i am getting the `error` while hitting the `url` of website.

Below is the `error`:

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Table 'resoninr_jooml29.resoninr_session' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `resoninr_session` WHERE `session_id` = 'gqcktvtop2kv33lc28ikjrhi44' LIMIT 0, 1

I am new to `joomla` and `database`. Can anybody please help me out to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done some analysis on this and below is the outcome:                             
The table name is "jos83_session" but when i have pushed it to bigrock server then there it is expecting table name as "resoninr_session"

Comment: so is there any way to rename all table name at once with what the error is expecting ??

Answer (score 0):

if you have all table prefix in the db is "jos83" then replace the value of "$dbprefix"  variable with the same prefix as in db("jos83") in the configuration.php at the root of joomla site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you have transferred the files and database. Through Akeeba or any third party extension or manually. If you transferred manually then there is less chance of change in `public $dbprefix = 'jos83_';` present in configuration file, as you need to change just the database user, database name and hostname in configuration.php file. 
Suppose you did through Akeeba then it will ask for a new prefix during site restoration. Suppose you did through Akeeba and still it doesnt work then your session table may be damaged. And if session table is damaged Joomla wont load. You have to manully delete the table and recreate it in phpmyadmin using this sql command

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `resoninr_session`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resoninr_session` (
`username` varchar(150) default '',
`time` varchar(14) default '',
`session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
`guest` tinyint(4) default '1',
`userid` int(11) default '0',
`usertype` varchar(50) default '',
`gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`data` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Some helpful links

1. http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=362525
2. [why does joomla 2.5 session table corrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909940/why-does-joomla-2-5-session-table-corrupt)
3. https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-session-crashed/