# Joomla 1.5.15 version site not displaying contents of article

Tags: php, joomla

The Joomla site which is down for maintenance due to hacking is not displaying the content of articles (front-end) in my local while executing. I am able to login to the backend and view the files. I am not sure, what exactly is happening. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can I get any suggestions? It might help me out a lot.

Comment: Clean up the website or restore from a clean backup and then update everything to the latest versions to prevent a recurrence: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19139389/1983389

Comment: Why on earth are you running Joomla 1.5.15??? Kep your site up to date and you're much less likely to get hacked!

Comment: @ Neil Roberston , I dont have a clean backup. I am trying to identify the infected code and to remove it.But anyways no article is displayed in frontend. Why this problem comes??