# Issue with Saxum IP Logger in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla

I became interested in the Saxum IP Logger component for Joomla after reading this stackoverflow question: [Joomla! 2.5.4 Hacked: Having trouble with diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036763/)

I have a Joomla 3.2.2 site, and I installed the Saxum component through the integrated component installer.  The version is the current one: 4.0.1.

My problems is that the "Reports" and the "Statistics" links on the admin screen results in a "white page" - i.e. no content loads.  All of the other portions of the Saxum tool work fine.

Normally, on a "white screen" issue within Joomla, I go to the Global Config and turn on debugging.  This usually results in a "friendly error" instead of just a white page.  But that did not work in this case.

In my list of plugins, I have the following:

- (enabled) Saxum IPLogger - User Plugin
- (disabled) Saxum IPLogger - System Plugin
- (disabled) Saxum IPLogger - Block IPs

I see the following database tables:

- saxum_iplogger (already 30 records since I installed this about an
  hour ago)
- saxum_iplogger_block
- saxum_iplogger_emails
- saxum_iplogger_excp

I can't post on their support forums because they charge $15 to join, and there hasn't been a post there in nearly 6 months.  I don't mind donating to anyone's project once I decide that I'm going to use it, but pay ahead of time for possibly non-existent support doesn't sit well with me.

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting from here.
Ideas or pointers welcome.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: I have just tried installing Saxum IP Logger on a test Joomla 3.2.2 site and on both the pages you mentioned, I get the error `Call to undefined method UsersHelper::getActions() in administrator/components/com_saxumiplogger/views/statistics/tmpl/default_user.php on line 15`. Due to this being a bug, I would suggest contacting them via their [Contact Page](http://saxum2003.hu/component/sexycontactform/?form=1&Itemid=207). If they do reply, please let me know what they say as it would be nice if they update this as I use this extension myself and am currently upgrading to Joomla 3.2

Answer (score 2):

The problem was reported on the [support forum of the extension](http://saxum2003.hu/en/kforum/bug-tracker/7-error-on-reports-and-statistics.html) and it is already resolved.

Comment: @helderdarocha: this is a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You are right. I made a mistake in flagging it.